# IIS listen only 127.0.0.1 instead 0.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, tcp, server

I configure binding on my IIS 7 server like:

```
ip address: All Unassigned
port: 8080
```

but in `netstat -aon` command see only `127.0.0.1:8080` instead `0.0.0.0:8080`(which I would like)

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 14):

Thanks to all. Problem is solved.

I use command:

```
netsh http show iplisten
```

and saw `127.0.0.1` in listening list. (But I didn't add it manually). So I delete it and add `0.0.0.0` instead.

```
netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=127.0.0.1

netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0
```

Then I restarted iis server.

Comment: I only needed to remove 127.0.0.1 to get IIS listening on all adapters again. There was no need for me to add 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Hi I had similar issue my application was not hosted in IIS, but I got this error even after adding as suggested can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69164288/msalclientexception-an-httplistenerexception-occurred-while-listening-on-http